# Why can 5rem hold 10 characters?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have been playing around with monofonts (because every character as wide as the next) to match length of input field.

How come `5rem` is equal to 10 characters? into my input field in both Chrome and Firefox? You would expect 10 characters to have width `10rem`:

```css
input[type="text"] {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  font-family: 'monospace';
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <form onSubmit="return false">
    <input type="text" placeholder="your name" maxlength="10" required />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
```

http://codepen.io/alfredwesterveld/pen/RrypPv

Comment: As a side-note the `rem` unit is relative to the "base font size" (that of the `html` tag) which your snippet didn't specify. Browsers default to 16px.

Comment: http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/WrJpxr

Comment: That input barely holds 7 `M`s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The unit you are looking for is `ch`: This unit represents the width of the character '0' in the current font. In a monospace font, `1ch` is equivalent of all character width.

```css
input {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 9ch;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="your name" maxlength="10" required />
```

To answer your question, monopsace characters have often a height two times bigger than their width. So `1ch ≈ 0.5em` and `5em ≈ 10ch`.

Comment: What does browser support for ch look like? I've never seen this before.

Comment: @Taylor The browser support of the `ch`unit is Chrome 27+, Firefox 1+, IE9+, Safari 7+

Comment: But this only works for monospace fonts? Also possible for all fonts only with css?

Comment: The unit is the width of the character '0' for every font, even non-monospace ones. As far as I know, it's near to `0.5em` most of the time.

Answer (score 5):

**The `rem` unit does not relate to the width of a character.**

The `em` property corresponds to the height of the font - not the width.

You might have better luck using the `ch` unit instead of `em` or `rem`; however, `ch` can differ from browser to browser (http://codepen.io/stffn/pen/BNGVRN)

Sources:

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props

[Specify width in *characters*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186457/specify-width-in-characters)

[How is font size calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495872/how-is-font-size-calculated)