# Rendering text with multiple lines in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, render

I am trying to make a game and I am trying to render a lot of text. When the text renders, the rest of the text goes off the screen. Is there any easy way to make the text go to the next line of the pygame window?

```
helpT = sys_font.render \
                ("This game is a combination of all of the trends\n of 2016. When you press 'Start Game,' a menu will pop up. In order to beat the game, you must get a perfect score on every single one of these games.",0,(hecolor))
        screen.blit(helpT,(0, 0))
```

Comment: You'll have to calculate it yourself. Render each word and check how many words can fit the screen by using `surface.get_width()`. Then blit the rest on the another row which will be `surface.get_height()` pixels lower.

Comment: `PyGame` doesn't render `\n` so you have to use `render` for every line separately.

Comment: as @TedKleinBergman alreadu said - you can get surface height. You can also get `next_line_rect = surface.get_rect()` and then `next_line_rect.top = prev_line_rect.bottom`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As I said in the comments; you have to render each word separately and calculate if the width of the text extends the width of the surface (or screen). Here's an example:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = (1024, 720)
FPS = 30
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE, pygame.RESIZABLE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def blit_text(surface, text, pos, font, color=pygame.Color('black')):
    words = [word.split(' ') for word in text.splitlines()]  # 2D array where each row is a list of words.
    space = font.size(' ')[0]  # The width of a space.
    max_width, max_height = surface.get_size()
    x, y = pos
    for line in words:
        for word in line:
            word_surface = font.render(word, 0, color)
            word_width, word_height = word_surface.get_size()
            if x + word_width >= max_width:
                x = pos[0]  # Reset the x.
                y += word_height  # Start on new row.
            surface.blit(word_surface, (x, y))
            x += word_width + space
        x = pos[0]  # Reset the x.
        y += word_height  # Start on new row.


text = "This is a really long sentence with a couple of breaks.\nSometimes it will break even if there isn't a break " \
       "in the sentence, but that's because the text is too long to fit the screen.\nIt can look strange sometimes.\n" \
       "This function doesn't check if the text is too high to fit on the height of the surface though, so sometimes " \
       "text will disappear underneath the surface"
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 64)

while True:

    dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

    screen.fill(pygame.Color('white'))
    blit_text(screen, text, (20, 20), font)
    pygame.display.update()
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/galatolofederico/aa43e0d3bfce5fd6173fb25c8b48e8f3) version of the function will do the same thing but always scroll to the bottom.

Answer (score 7):

There is no easy way to render text on multiple  lines in pygame, but this helper function could provide some use to you. Just pass in your text (with newlines), x, y, and font size.

```
def render_multi_line(text, x, y, fsize)
        lines = text.splitlines()
        for i, l in enumerate(lines):
            screen.blit(sys_font.render(l, 0, hecolor), (x, y + fsize*i))
```

Comment: The font size is not the same as the character height though. [There's no standard way to figure out how tall a certain character might be at any given size, aside from rendering the font.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3496463/6486738) Also, `sys_font` and `hecolor` are undefined in your function. I'd suggest passing a font object instead of the font size and then set `text_height = font.size(lines[0])[1]`. This will allow you to do `screen.blit(font.render(l, 0, color), (x, y + text_height*i))`. You'd also need to a parameter for the `color`.

Comment: You can use [font.get_linesize()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.get_linesize) to get the line height of a font.

Answer (score 3):

There is no automatic solution. You have to implement the text wrap by yourself and draw the text line by line respectively word by word.
Fortunately PyGame wiki provides a function that for this task. See PyGame wiki [Simple Text Wrapping for pygame](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/TextWrap).

I've extended the function and added an additional argument, which provides *left* or *right* aligned text, *centerd* text or even *block* mode.

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-TextWrap](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-TextWrap#main.py)</kbd>

[image][image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)

textAlignLeft = 0
textAlignRight = 1
textAlignCenter = 2
textAlignBlock = 3

def drawText(surface, text, color, rect, font, align=textAlignLeft, aa=False, bkg=None):
    lineSpacing = -2
    spaceWidth, fontHeight = font.size(" ")[0], font.size("Tg")[1]

    listOfWords = text.split(" ")
    if bkg:
        imageList = [font.render(word, 1, color, bkg) for word in listOfWords]
        for image in imageList: image.set_colorkey(bkg)
    else:
        imageList = [font.render(word, aa, color) for word in listOfWords]

    maxLen = rect[2]
    lineLenList = [0]
    lineList = [[]]
    for image in imageList:
        width = image.get_width()
        lineLen = lineLenList[-1] + len(lineList[-1]) * spaceWidth + width
        if len(lineList[-1]) == 0 or lineLen <= maxLen:
            lineLenList[-1] += width
            lineList[-1].append(image)
        else:
            lineLenList.append(width)
            lineList.append([image])

    lineBottom = rect[1]
    lastLine = 0
    for lineLen, lineImages in zip(lineLenList, lineList):
        lineLeft = rect[0]
        if align == textAlignRight:
            lineLeft += + rect[2] - lineLen - spaceWidth * (len(lineImages)-1)
        elif align == textAlignCenter:
            lineLeft += (rect[2] - lineLen - spaceWidth * (len(lineImages)-1)) // 2
        elif align == textAlignBlock and len(lineImages) > 1:
            spaceWidth = (rect[2] - lineLen) // (len(lineImages)-1)
        if lineBottom + fontHeight > rect[1] + rect[3]:
            break
        lastLine += 1
        for i, image in enumerate(lineImages):
            x, y = lineLeft + i*spaceWidth, lineBottom
            surface.blit(image, (round(x), y))
            lineLeft += image.get_width() 
        lineBottom += fontHeight + lineSpacing

    if lastLine < len(lineList):
        drawWords = sum([len(lineList[i]) for i in range(lastLine)])
        remainingText = ""
        for text in listOfWords[drawWords:]: remainingText += text + " "
        return remainingText
    return ""

msg = "Simple function that will draw text and wrap it to fit the rect passed.  If there is any text that will not fit into the box, the remaining text will be returned."
textRect = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 300, 300)

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 0), textRect, 1)
    drawTextRect = textRect.inflate(-5, -5)
    drawText(window, msg, (0, 0, 0), drawTextRect, font, textAlignBlock, True)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 3):

This will be similar to what others have posted, but I figured I'd upload my own code too:

```
    def box_text(surface, font, x_start, x_end, y_start, text, colour):
        x = x_start
        y = y_start
        words = text.split(' ')

        for word in words:
            word_t = font.render(word, True, colour)
            if word_t.get_width() + x <= x_end:
                surface.blit(word_t, (x, y))
                x += word_t.get_width() * 1.1
            else:
                y += word_t.get_height() * 1.1
                x = x_start
                surface.blit(word_t, (x, y))
                x += word_t.get_width() * 1.1
```

I think it's rather self explanatory:

- You enter the coordinates of where you want your text to start (x_start, y_start) and where it should end (x_end)
- The code loops through all words of your text, only adding them to the screen if their width is inferior to the the space left in the line. If that’s not the case, a new line is started at x_start with the y coordinates being increased by slightly more than your font’s height.

An example of when I used in a personal project:

```
x_start = self.W / 2 - info_box.get_width() / 2 + 10

self.box_text(self.WINDOW, self.info_font, x_start, x_start + 430, self.H / 3 + 10, self.mage_text, self.white)
```

If you want the text to be justified, you could go until the end of the line without actually adding the words to the screen, calculate the space left at the end of the line, and then loop through the line again with a modified “space length”, thereby arriving exactly at your box edge with your last word.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the [`ptext`](https://github.com/cosmologicon/pygame-text) library which is able to recognize newline (`\n`) characters. You only need to call `ptext.draw(text, position)`.

```
import pygame as pg
import ptext


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue')
# Triple quoted strings contain newline characters.
text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."""

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    ptext.draw(text, (10, 10), color=BLUE)  # Recognizes newline characters.
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pg.quit()
```

[image: pygame multiline text]

Answer (score 2):

As of `pygame-ce` (a modern distribution of `pygame`) version `2.1.4` [`pygame.Font.render`](https://pyga.me/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) now has newline (`"\n"`) and wraplength (the width in pixels before wrapping to a new line) support.

Thus with these new and shiny features, solving this issue becomes a piece of cake, you just pass the text you want to `pygame.Font.render` and specify the window width as the last argument so that it wraps once the text reaches the width of the window. Since this method doesn't yet accept keyword arguments you must provide the background colour argument too, it can be `None` or you can provide a colour value with an alpha value of 0.

### Here is a short code example:

```py
import pygame


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 360
FPS = 60

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.Font(None, 32)
text_surf = font.render(
    "This game is a combination of all of the trends\n "
    "of 2016. When you press 'Start Game,' a menu will pop up. "
    "In order to beat the game, you must get a perfect score on every single one of these games.",
    True,
    "white",
    None,  # or (0, 0, 0, 0) for example
    WIDTH,
)

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    screen.fill("black")

    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.blit(text_surf, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

### And the result:

[image]

Additionally to install the latest version of `pygame-ce` simply follow these steps:

1. `pip uninstall pygame` (to avoid conflict, this has to be done only if you have `pygame` installed already)
2. `pip install pygame-ce`
3. Enjoy the new and shiny features

More info about the fork can be found here: [Pygame: Community Edition Announcement](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/1112q10/pygame_community_edition_announcement/)
And the version specific announcement here: [Pygame-ce 2.1.4 release](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/11irmbo/pygamece_214_release/)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it

```
amfolyt_beskrivelse_text = ['en amfolyt er et stof som både kan være en base, eller syre','så som']
    for x in amfolyt_beskrivelse_text:
        descriptioncounter += 1
        screen.blit((pygame.font.SysFont('constantia',12).render(x, True, BLACK)),(300,10*descriptioncounter))
    descriptioncounter = 0
```

but of course, I can only do that because my text starts a line distance from the top of the screen. If you start further down the screen you could do

```
(300,12+12*descriptioncounter)
```

Answer (score 1):

Created this function that could help a bit :) Just make sure that each new paragraph is a new item on the list you are calling on this function.

```
def multilineText(Surface, textAsList: list, font: str, size: int, colour, antialias: bool, centerTupleCoord: tuple, spaceBetweenLines: int):
    xPosition = centerTupleCoord[0]
    yPosition = centerTupleCoord[1]
    for paragraph in textAsList:
        fontObjsrt = pygame.font.SysFont(font, size)
        TextSurf = fontObjsrt.render(paragraph, antialias, colour)
        TextRect = TextSurf.get_rect()
        TextRect.center = (xPosition, yPosition)
        Surface.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        yPosition += spaceBetweenLines
```

Answer (score -1):

One thing you could do is use a monospaced font. They have the same size for all characters and so are beloved by programmers.  That's going to be my solution for handling the height/width problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a .json file to load each line.

.json file (called first.json):

```
["Hello!", "How's it going?"]
```

And then load it into the file:

```
sys_font = pygame.font.SysFont(("Arial"),30)

def message_box(text):
    pos = 560 # depends on message box location
    pygame.draw.rect(root, (0,0,0), (100, 550, 800, 200)) #rectangle position varies
    for x in range(len(text)):
        rendered = sys_font.render(text[x], 0, (255,255,255))
        root.blit(rendered, ( 110, pos))
        pos += 30 # moves the following line down 30 pixels

with open('first.json') as text:
    message_box(json.load(text))
```

Don't forget to `import json`

Result: [image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Building on previous answers I made a somewhat comprehensive blit text function I can use with a single short command:

```py
def blittext(text, **kwargs):
    #blit text into screen, uses defaults and works for multiline strings
    fontface = kwargs.get('font', 'PressStart2P-Regular.ttf')
    b = kwargs.get('bold', False)
    fontsize = kwargs.get('size', 30)
    color = kwargs.get('color', (255, 255, 255))
    topleft = kwargs.get('topleft',(w/2,h/2))
    center = kwargs.get('center')
    textsurf = kwargs.get('surface',surface)
    maxwidth = kwargs.get('width',w)
    try:
        myfont = pygame.font.Font('/storage/emulated/0/games/' + fontface, fontsize)
    except:
        myfont = pygame.font.SysFont(fontface, fontsize, bold=b)
    x,y = topleft
    charwidth = myfont.size(' ')[0]
    charheight = fontsize + 3
    
    if center:
        for l in text.splitlines():
            mytext = myfont.render(l, False, color)
            textrect = mytext.get_rect(center=center)
            center = (center[0],center[1]+charheight)
            textsurf.blit(mytext,textrect)      
    else:
        for line in text.splitlines():
            for word in line.split(' '):
                mytext = myfont.render(word, False, color)
                textrect = mytext.get_rect(topleft=(x,y))
                wordwidth = textrect.width
                if x + wordwidth >= maxwidth:
                    x,y = (topleft[0], y + charheight)
                textsurf.blit(mytext,(x,y))
                x += charwidth + wordwidth
            x,y = (topleft[0], y + charheight)
```

Answer (score -1):

**text_ml_surface** create the Surface.

Reuse created surface for save your resources efficiently and manage the output, for example for scroll.

```
from pygame import SRCALPHA
from pygame import Color, Surface
from pygame.font import Font

SURFACE_ARGS = dict(flags=SRCALPHA, depth=32)

def text_ml_surface(font_obj: Font, ml_text: str, color: str, width: int) -> Surface:
    words_by_lines = [line.split(' ') for line in ml_text.splitlines()]
    space_width = font_obj.size(' ')[0]
    color_obj = Color(color)
    font_line_height = font_obj.get_linesize()

    # get height
    x, y = 0, 0
    for line in words_by_lines:
        for word in line:
            word_width = font_obj.size(word)[0]
            if x + word_width >= width:
                x = 0
                y += font_line_height
            x += word_width + space_width
        x = 0
        y += font_line_height

    # render
    surface = Surface((width, y), **SURFACE_ARGS)
    x, y = 0, 0
    for line in words_by_lines:
        for word in line:
            word_surface = font_obj.render(word, True, color_obj)
            word_width = word_surface.get_size()[0]
            if x + word_width >= width:
                x = 0
                y += font_line_height
            surface.blit(word_surface, (x, y))
            x += word_width + space_width
        x = 0
        y += font_line_height

    return surface
```