# Rendering content from a text file in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, render

I would like some help with my python code. I am trying to render my high scores from a text file onto a new screen. Im able to open a new window when I push a button called high scores. It displays the high scores horizontal and runs off the screen. I would like it to be displayed vertically

Before I was displaying on console and now I was able to open a new window and renders text. However, I'm unsuccessfully displaying it correctly. I need it to display as
score name
score name
score name
score name
Here is the current display
[Current high scores display picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT2dt.png)

```py
def check_play_button(ai_settings, screen, stats, sb, play_button, play_button_high_scores, ship, aliens, bullets, mouse_x, mouse_y):
    """Displays high scores when clicked """
    GREEN = (0, 200, 0 )
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
    text_color = (GREEN)
    # Set the background color.
    bg_color = (0, 0, 0)
    high_scores = []
    button_clicked = play_button_high_scores.rect.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y)
    if button_clicked and not stats.game_active:
        f = open('high_score.txt', 'r')
        file_contents = f.read()
        f.close()

        #score_image = font.render('test', True, text_color, ai_settings.bg_color)
        X = 400
        Y = 400
        display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y ))
        pygame.display.set_caption('HIGH SCORES')
        font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 12)
        text = font.render(str(file_contents), True, text_color, bg_color)
        textRect = text.get_rect()
        textRect.center = (X // 2, Y // 2)

        while True :
            # completely fill the surface object
            # with white color
            display_surface.fill(bg_color)

            # copying the text surface object
            # to the display surface object
            # at the center coordinate.
            display_surface.blit(text, textRect)

            # iterate over the list of Event objects
            # that was returned by pygame.event.get() method.
            for event in pygame.event.get() :

                # if event object type is QUIT
                # then quitting the pygame
                # and program both.
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT :

                    # deactivates the pygame library
                    pygame.quit()

                    # quit the program.
                    quit()

                # Draws the surface object to the screen.
                pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You might want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014195/rendering-text-with-multiple-lines-in-pygame/42015712