# Pygame lagging with texts

Tags: python, text, pygame, lag

I was creating my Cuphead inspired game, a fan game and I was creating the warning text and it is lagging a lot like 0-2 fps if anyone can help me I would be very grateful, I don't know if programming on the cell phone interferes with anything or it's the same thing but anyway if you can help me thank you

My code:

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()

resolutions = ['1152, 648', '1280, 720', '1365, 768', '1600, 900', '1920, 1080']

screen_max = ((1920, 1080))
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_max), pygame.FULLSCREEN | pygame.SCALED)

game_fontT = int(screen_max[0]/30)
game_font = pygame.font.Font('Fonts/AlegreyaSansSC-Bold.ttf', int(game_fontT))

FPS = 60
click = False

linguas = ['espanhol', 'ingles', 'portugues']

lingua = linguas[2]

Warn_Screen = True

def show_fps():
    fr = str(int(clock.get_fps()))
    frt = game_font.render(str(fr), 1, pygame.Color("coral"))
    return frt

def text(text, posx, posy, R, G, B):
    posx = int(posx)
    posy = int(posy)
    R = int(R)
    G = int(G)
    B = int(B)
    score_surface = game_font.render(f'{text}', True, (R, G, B))
    score_rect = score_surface.get_rect(center = (posx, posy))
    rgb_surface1 = game_font.render(f'{text}', True, (0, 255, 0))
    rgb_rect1 = score_surface.get_rect(center = (posx-1, posy-1))
    rgb_surface2 = game_font.render(f'{text}', True, (255, 0, 0))
    rgb_rect2 = score_surface.get_rect(center = (posx+1, posy+1))
    screen.blit(rgb_surface1, rgb_rect1)
    screen.blit(rgb_surface2, rgb_rect2)
    screen.blit(score_surface, score_rect)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    screen.fill([255, 207, 17])
    ftr = show_fps()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            click = True
        
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            click = False
                        
    if Warn_Screen:
        if lingua == linguas[2]:
            text('aviso', screen_max[0]/2, 45, 0, 0, 0)
            text(f'Todas as coisas desse jogo pertencem ao studio MDHR', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-310, 0, 0, 0)
            text('Tudo que você está jogando aqui é apenas uma recriação', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-260, 0, 0, 0)
            text('Todas as músicas, sprites, efeitos, fontes pertencem ao Studio MDHR', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-210, 0, 0, 0)
            text('Essa é apenas uma recriação feita por um fã', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-160, 0, 0, 0)
            text('Então quando puder compre o original', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-110, 0, 0, 0)
            text('Você não irá se arrepender.', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-60, 0, 0, 0)
        
        if lingua == linguas[0]:
            text('Advertencia', screen_max[0]/2, 45, 0, 0, 0)
            text('Todo el material de este juego pertenece al estudio MDHR', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-310, 0, 0, 0)
            text('Todo lo que estás jugando aquí es solo una recreación', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-260, 0, 0, 0)
            text('Todas las canciones, sprites, efectos, fuentes pertenecen a MDHR', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-210, 0, 0, 0)
            text('Esta es solo una recreación hecha por fanáticos', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-160, 0, 0, 0)
            text('Así que cuando puedas comprar el original', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-110, 0, 0, 0)
            text('No te arrepentirás.', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-60, 0, 0, 0)
            
        if lingua == linguas[1]:
            text('Warning', screen_max[0]/2, 45, 0, 0, 0)
            text('All stuff in this game belongs to MDHR studio', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-310, 0, 0, 0)
            text("Everything you're playing here is just a recreation", screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-260, 0, 0, 0)
            text('All songs, sprites, effects, fonts belong to Studio MDHR', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-210, 0, 0, 0)
            text('This is just a fan-made recreation', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-160, 0, 0, 0)
            text('So when you can buy the original', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-110, 0, 0, 0)
            text('You will not regret.', screen_max[0]/2, screen_max[1]/2-60, 0, 0, 0)
        
        if click:
            Warn_Screen = False
            
    screen.blit(ftr, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: The text is static, so instead of rendering the text every frame, draw the text on a surface before the application loop and [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) that surface every frame.

Comment: i'm a little new to pygame so i had a hard time getting this to a surface could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The text is static, so instead of rendering the text every frame, draw the text on a surface before the application loop and [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) that surface every frame.

Write a function that draws a text with multiple lines on a transparent [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html).A transparent surface can be created with the flag `SRCAPHA`:

```py
def renderText(font, color, textList):
    fontHeihgt = font.get_height()
    textSurfaceList = [font.render(t, True, color) for t in textList]
    width = max([s.get_width() for s in textSurfaceList])
    height = len(textSurfaceList) * fontHeihgt
    textSurface = pygame.Surface((width, height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    [textSurface.blit(s, (0, fontHeihgt*i)) for i, s in enumerate(textSurfaceList)]
    return textSurface
```

See also [Rendering text with multiple lines in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014195/rendering-text-with-multiple-lines-in-pygame/64598520#64598520).

Use this function and render the text before the application loop and `blit` the text inside the loop.

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def renderText(font, color, textList):
    fontHeihgt = font.get_height()
    textSurfaceList = [font.render(t, True, color) for t in textList]
    width = max([s.get_width() for s in textSurfaceList])
    height = len(textSurfaceList) * fontHeihgt
    textSurface = pygame.Surface((width, height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    [textSurface.blit(s, (0, fontHeihgt*i)) for i, s in enumerate(textSurfaceList)]
    return textSurface

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
text = renderText(font, (255, 255, 0), ["This is a", "multi-line text.", ";-)"])

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window_center = window.get_rect().center
    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(text, text.get_rect(center = window_center))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```