# I have this function for a pygame game that I'm doing, but I'm having some issues coding my "Pause screen"

Tags: pygame

Basically, I have this function for showing an answer when the button p is pressed. I tried two ways:

```py
def check_pause(self):
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_p:            
            if self.pause == False:
                self.pause = True
                print("paused")
            elif self.pause == True:
                self.pause = False
                print("not paused")
```

and:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        
if keys[pygame.K_p] and keys[pygame.KEYDOWN]:
    if self.pause == False:
        self.pause = True
        print("paused")
    elif self.pause == True:
        self.pause = False
        print("unpaused")
```

With the first one, it barely reacts. The answer is too slow when I press multiple times. And the second way is too sensitive, it keeps going through "Paused" and "Unpaused" really quickly. I would like it to react at the time when I press my key.

Answer (score 0):

The problems are likely due to attempting to handle events in multiple places and not limiting the frame rate.

Here's an example that toggles the visibility of a question and answer by pressing <kbd>P</kbd>:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
# grab the first installed font
sys_font = pygame.font.SysFont(pygame.font.get_fonts()[0], 28)
question_text = "What is the answer to the ultimate question?"
question = sys_font.render(question_text, True, pygame.Color("turquoise"))
answer_text =  "42"
answer = sys_font.render(answer_text, True, pygame.Color("red"))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
width, height = 640, 480
icon = sys_font.render("??", True, pygame.Color("red"))
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
pygame.display.set_caption("Ultimate Question")

show_answer = False
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                # toggle answer visibility
                show_answer = ~show_answer  
    
    # Graphics
    screen.fill("black")
    # Draw Text in the center
    if show_answer:
        screen.blit(answer, answer.get_rect(center=screen.get_rect().center))
    else:
        screen.blit(question, question.get_rect(center=screen.get_rect().center))
    # Update Screen
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
pygame.quit()
```

This looks like:
[image: example questioner]

Comment: Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42015712) for rendering multi-line text.